# perl exact string match

Tags: perl

I have following Perl code to prompt user for yes/no answer. If the user enters anything else than yes/no, keep prompting. No other word is acceptable. I don't know why this code doesn't work. I tested with answer "noooooo" and I was expecting it to prompt again but it does not enter the while loop.

Can anyone help find my mistake here?

```
@files = A, B, C;

foreach $c (@files) {
  if (-e $c  ) { 
     print " $c already exists. Do you want to overwrite?  (yes or no): ";
     chomp ($file_yes_no = <STDIN>);

     while ($file_yes_no !~ m/yes{1}|no{1}/i )  {
         print "$c already exists. Do you want to overwrite?  (yes or no): ";
         chomp ($file_yes_no = <STDIN>);
     }

     if ($file_yes_no =~ m/yes/i ) {
         if (system ("cp -f /home/old_path/ /home/new_path/ == 0) {
             print "$c successfully copied;
         } else {
             die "Error: Copy failed, Check the message above";
         }
     }
 else { print "No files copied\n; }
```

Comment: Use `File::Copy` to copy a file. `use File::Copy qw(copy); copy($src, $dest) or die $!;`

Comment: how about `do { print ...; chomp ... } while condition;`.  better yet, http://p3rl.org/IO::Prompt

Comment: Are you using `use warnings; use strict;`?

Answer (score 10):

I would just use the string equality operator `eq` instead of a regex.

```
if( $file_yes_no eq 'yes' ) ...
```

If I wanted it case insensitive I'd first convert to lowercase with `lc`.

The problem with your regex is it will happily match any string *containing* the letters `yes` sequentially.  If you wish, you can match the start and end of the string like this:

```
if ($file_yes_no =~ m/^yes$/i ) ...
```

But I personally prefer the first option.

Oh, I missed the first part...  Hmmmm.  Same deal, if you *must* use regex.

```
m/^(yes|no)$/i
```

Once again I'd be more inclined to avoid regex

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried with ^ and $ and it worked. I tried "ne" instead of !~  and it did not work -- it still skips while when I answer "nooooo" ...notice the OR in there...is that correct?

while ($file_yes_no ne "yes" || $file_yes_no ne "no") {

Comment: No, you should use `&&`.  The reason being that it will *always* be not one thing OR not the other.

Answer (score 3):

You should use following Perl regular expression for matching only `yes` or `no` (case insensitive):

```
m/^(yes|no)$/i
```

For yes only, use:

```
m/^yes$/i
```

Comment: use `\A` and `\z`, not `^` and `$`, or you will match other strings too (e.g. `"yes\n"`)

Comment: @ysth, this is matching on a single line from `STDIN`.  Multi-line input will not occur.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using a regular expression. You could write the regular expression to match the beginning or end of the string ... like this:

```
while( $file_yes_no !~ /^(yes|no)$/ ) {
```

The `^` and `$` are the beginning and end of the string. Also you can omit the `m`.

Or you could just check the values explicitly:

```
while( $file_yes_no ne "yes" and $file_yes_no ne "no" ) {
```

Also you have a typo in your system command but I'm assuming that was just copying it here. You really shouldn't branch out to a shell for that. Look into `File::Copy` which gives you a `copy` function

Comment: You should be more careful: `"yesss!" =~ /^yes|no$/` is true.