# Regular expression for the usage of +

Tags: regex, perl

Here is my code. I want to print out all the lines at the beginning of capital:

```
while(<>){
    if(/^[A-Z][a-z]+/){
        print;
    }
}
```

`test.txt`:

```
Fred
fred
FRED
FreD
```

After I execute the command:

```
perl sc.pl test.txt

Fred
FreD
```

Why the `FreD` will be printed out? I have use `[a-z]+`, it seems that the `+`  only match the lower case expect the last one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [perl exact string match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699822/perl-exact-string-match)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The string `FreD` matches `/^[A-Z][a-z]+/` because `[A-Z]` matches `F` and `[a-z]+` matches `re`.

To get the desired result, anchor the end of the regex as well: `/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/`.

See also [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

*(Edit: I see now that @Biffen has provided the same answer in the comments, sorry)*